# Prevent init daemon echoing on TTY

Tags: bash, rhel, perl, init-script, daemon

Below is an `init` script which starts/stops a daemon. The daemon is unfortunately printing the parsed packet data (from `/home/nuthan/program/server`), a socket server written in perl, listening to a socket for tcp packets from a client.

As soon as I start the service, the parsed data (print statements from `/home/nuthan/program/server`) is echoed on my TTY. And, if I try to kill the terminal, the daemon quits. How do I overcome this?

**daemon and logging packet data command**

```
 daemon -18 perl /home/nuthan/program/server -d -v -r -f -O=/var/log/vts.log --daemon
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# vts      Start/Stop Vts.
#
# description: VTS daemon for vehicle Tracking.
# Source function library
. /etc/init.d/functions

# Get network config
. /etc/sysconfig/network

RETVAL=0

start() {
echo -n $"Starting vts: "
# Start me up!
daemon -18 perl /home/nuthan/program/server -d -v -r -f -O=/var/log/vts.log --daemon
RETVAL=$?
echo
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/vts
    touch /var/lock/subsys/vts
return $RETVAL

}

stop() {
echo -n $"Stopping vts: "
killproc vts
RETVAL=$?
echo
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/vtsdaemon
return $RETVAL
}

restart() {
  stop
start
}

reload() {
stop
start
}

case "$1" in
  start)
  start
;;
  stop)
  stop
;;
  status)
status vts
;;
  restart)
  restart
;;
  condrestart)
  [ -f /var/lock/subsys/vts ] && restart || :
;;
  reload)
reload
;;
  *)
echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|reload}"
exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Where does the `daemon` command come from and what is its usage syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing three commands: **`deamon`**, **`perl`** and **`/home/nuthan/program/server`** without any quotes. Think about the following: *How does each of them know, which of the parameters it should interpret?*

The syntax you used could probably only be correctly interpreted, if:

- `deamon` would treat everything after `-18` to be the command to run
- `perl` would interpret only the first parameter (`/home/nuthan/program/server`) as the script to run, and all that follows as parameters passed **to that script**

I can suggest two things to fix the issues:

1. Make sure whether you need to call `perl` explicitly. If the `server` script contains a proper interpreter declaration (probably `/usr/bin/perl`) on its first line, and it has executable bit set, you should not need to explicitly call `perl`.
2. Check the syntax of the `daemon` command. If it indicates that everything after `-18` (in your command) should be treated as a full command to run, then it's ok. Otherwise, you might either need to everything that follows in quotes, or put create an additional *function* or a *wrapper script* that would run your entire command - so the entire command line you've written would be changed to `daemon -18 your_function` or `daemon -18 /path/to/your/wrapper_script.sh`.

Comment: many thnx... finally, the daemon and perl has to be separated using quotes: `daemon -18 "perl /home/nuthan/program/server >/dev/null -d -v -r -f -O=/var/log/vts.log --daemon" 2>&1 1>/home/nuthan/program/vts.log &` This worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
daemon -18 perl /home/nuthan/program/server -d -v -r -f -O=/var/log/vts.log --daemon
RETVAL=$? 2>&1 1>/some/where/over_the_rainbow
```

But note, that it looks like the -O should already do it some of the sort, as should that "daemon" so there could be more ti this than meets the eye.

Comment: thnx for the answer. Now, /some/where/over_the_rainbow logs the print statements. But, still i'm not able to detach tty from the daemon.Dont know why!!!

Answer (score 0):

You would overcome this by redirecting `stdout` to the abyss (`/dev/null`) and redirect `stderr` to where `stdout` is redirected. `/dev/null` discards everything it recieves. So something like this could work:

```
daemon -18 perl /home/nuthan/program/server -d -v -r -f -O=/var/log/vts.log --daemon >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: redirecting to /dev/null is not working. i cannot detach tty from the daemon.